# how to pass a table name dynamically in mysql using jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
String query = "SELECT SUM(totalcost) FROM"+m+""; //where totalcost is my column name

    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);                  


    while(rs.next())
    {

    System.out.println("SUM(user_id)="+rs.getString(1));                              

    }
```

what is wrong in this code? my exception is:

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'totalcost' in 'field list'**

Comment: You are missing a space after `from`. Without it, it will end up as `... fromtablename ...`

Comment: The error message means that the table doesn't have a column called totalcost. Does it?

Comment: @juergend after give the gap still i got the same exception

Comment: @Joni my table having column  totalcost

Comment: MySQL thinks differently. Maybe you have the wrong table, or the wrong database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding a space after the `from` tag;

```
String query = "SELECT SUM(totalcost) FROM "+m+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm you have a column in the database called "totalcost" for the table you are referencing?  If so, I'm thinking that the table name may be incorrect when you substitute the "m" variable.

Also, I would use a prepared statement to build the MySQL query.  Let me know if you need more help.

You don't need to worry about using "AS totalcost" on the SUM(totalcost) part of the query, as when selecting the result, you are selecting: "rs.getString(1)" which will return the value in the first column of the row in the resultset.

Comment: yeah it cofirm i having a column name totalcost,i use prepared statement also but it also won't work.

Comment: @jeff storey  m is represented by my tablename given by dynamically

Comment: Can you verify that the table name you are passing to MySQL matches exactly. Depending on the underlying operating system and database engine, the table name may be case-sensitive; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html